# Exception: Unable to serialize node of type <class 'set'> on calling getuser in ebay-sdk python

Tags: python, ebay-sdk

I am using [ebay-sdk Python usage documentation](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/wiki/Trading-API-Class).

I get this error

```
Exception: Unable to serialize node of type <class 'set'> ({'genuinefeatherbuys2011'})
```

Here is my code (I replaced some data with 'x')

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError


key_id  = 'x'
dev_id  = 'x'
cert_id = 'x'
mytoken = 'x'

try:
    api = Trading(appid=key_id, devid=dev_id, certid=cert_id, token=mytoken, config_file=None)
    response = api.execute('GetUser', {'genuinefeatherbuys2011'})
    print(response.dict())
    print(response.reply)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution while checking samples.
The `'UserID':` needed to be added.

See adapted code below:

```
try:
    api = Trading(appid=key_id, devid=dev_id, certid=cert_id, token=mytoken, config_file=None)
    response = api.execute('GetUser', {'UserID': 'sallyma789'})
    print(response.dict())
    print(response.reply)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```